# How to send HTML text and attachment using boto3 send_email or send_raw_email?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

How can I send an image attachment using  [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/) SES `send_email` client?

I know that I can use `send_raw_email` to send an attachment but I need to send the message body with `html data`. If this is not possible, how can I send an email with html data using boto3.ses.send_raw_email() ?

Comment: In fact, there is not such things as "html email" , it is merely email `data` with html tag. So this has nothing to do with boto3.send_mail API,  you just draft the data in compliant html and supported mime header and submit them.

Comment: I know there's no html email, just bad English. The data needs to be html. Then how do I add the header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shameless copy example from "[HOW TO SEND HTML MAILS USING AMAZON SES](https://ashishb.net/tech/how-to-send-html-mails-using-amazon-ses-simple-email-service-in-python/) "
This is how a typical email data content looks like.

```
 message_dict = { 'Data':
  'From: ' + mail_sender + '\n'
  'To: ' + mail_receivers_list + '\n'
  'Subject: ' + mail_subject + '\n'
  'MIME-Version: 1.0\n'
  'Content-Type: text/html;\n\n' +
  mail_content}
```

If you want to send attachment and HTML text using [boto3.ses.send_raw_email](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_raw_email), you just need use above message dict and pass. (just put your html text under the mail_content)

```
response = client.send_raw_email(
    Destinations=[
    ],
    FromArn='',
    RawMessage=message_dict,
    ReturnPathArn='',
    Source='',
    SourceArn='',
)
```

In fact,  the raw attachment header should works in both send_email()  and send_raw_email() . Except in send_mail, you should put the attachment inside `Text`, not `html`.

Comment: This is not using the SES client

Comment: @Dko :  this is the data format that you give to boto3.ses.send_mail

Comment: It might be that you're misunderstanding my struggle. I know how to send the email with html data using the api, but I don't know how I can attach an attachment to this email. I know how to do it by using `send_raw_mail` but then, and only then, I don't know how I can send html data with *raw* mail.

Comment: it doesn't send as attachment tho

Comment: @JonEkiz  You can refer to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2183  to construct the correct content for attachment. Or you can look around for similar example.

Answer (score 47):

After going through several sources, including other SO questions, blogs and Python documentation, I came up with the code below.

Allows for text and/or html emails and attachments.

Separated the MIME and boto3 parts, in case you want to re-use MIME for other purposes, like sending an email with a SMTP client, instead of boto3.

```
import os
import boto3
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


def create_multipart_message(
        sender: str, recipients: list, title: str, text: str=None, html: str=None, attachments: list=None)\
        -> MIMEMultipart:
    """
    Creates a MIME multipart message object.
    Uses only the Python `email` standard library.
    Emails, both sender and recipients, can be just the email string or have the format 'The Name <the_email@host.com>'.

    :param sender: The sender.
    :param recipients: List of recipients. Needs to be a list, even if only one recipient.
    :param title: The title of the email.
    :param text: The text version of the email body (optional).
    :param html: The html version of the email body (optional).
    :param attachments: List of files to attach in the email.
    :return: A `MIMEMultipart` to be used to send the email.
    """
    multipart_content_subtype = 'alternative' if text and html else 'mixed'
    msg = MIMEMultipart(multipart_content_subtype)
    msg['Subject'] = title
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)

    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    if text:
        part = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        msg.attach(part)
    if html:
        part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
        msg.attach(part)

    # Add attachments
    for attachment in attachments or []:
        with open(attachment, 'rb') as f:
            part = MIMEApplication(f.read())
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(attachment))
            msg.attach(part)

    return msg


def send_mail(
        sender: str, recipients: list, title: str, text: str=None, html: str=None, attachments: list=None) -> dict:
    """
    Send email to recipients. Sends one mail to all recipients.
    The sender needs to be a verified email in SES.
    """
    msg = create_multipart_message(sender, recipients, title, text, html, attachments)
    ses_client = boto3.client('ses')  # Use your settings here
    return ses_client.send_raw_email(
        Source=sender,
        Destinations=recipients,
        RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()}
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sender_ = 'The Sender <the_sender@email.com>'
    recipients_ = ['Recipient One <recipient_1@email.com>', 'recipient_2@email.com']
    title_ = 'Email title here'
    text_ = 'The text version\nwith multiple lines.'
    body_ = """<html><head></head><body><h1>A header 1</h1><br>Some text."""
    attachments_ = ['/path/to/file1/filename1.txt', '/path/to/file2/filename2.txt']

    response_ = send_mail(sender_, recipients_, title_, text_, body_, attachments_)
    print(response_)
```

Comment: I had written a flavour of that code for my projects but I started noticing that attachments would not go through in certain mail clients like MacOS Mail (even when you configure the IMAP connection to download attachments). Have you observed the same thing?

Comment: What I have here is what I'm using and haven't had any problems with attachments. That said, I'm using Outlook as client, not sure if MacOS Mail works any differently, but shouldn't.. I've been able to send both text (html) files binary (zip) files, haven't tried other file types, but don't think that would be an issue.

Comment: I found the fix: you need to create a parent container of type MIMEMultipart('mixed') and then attach it first a child container of type MIMEMultipart('alternative') plus the attachment itself ;-)

Comment: Nice. To inline an image using this solution you'll need to include the `Content-Id` in the attachment and then refer to it in the html. For example, modify the above to attach a content-id header such as `part.add_header('Content-Id', f'<{content_id}>)` and make sure to refer to the image in the body with a tag:
`<img width=500 height=500 id="1" src="cid:{content_id}'">`. Here I'm using `f-strings` and interpolating with an assumed `content_id` variable.

Comment: You don't have to define `Source` and `Destinations` in `ses_client.send_raw_email` if they're already part of `msg`

Answer (score 10):

**March 2019**

Here is a copy-pasted solution from the **UPDATED** official documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html):

```
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

# Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = "Sender Name <sender@example.com>"

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = "recipient@example.com"

# Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
# set, comment the following variable, and the 
# ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET argument below.
CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"

# If necessary, replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"

# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "Customer service contact info"

# The full path to the file that will be attached to the email.
ATTACHMENT = "path/to/customers-to-contact.xlsx"

# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
BODY_TEXT = "Hello,\r\nPlease see the attached file for a list of customers to contact."

# The HTML body of the email.
BODY_HTML = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "utf-8"

# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

# Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
# Add subject, from and to lines.
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT 
msg['From'] = SENDER 
msg['To'] = RECIPIENT

# Create a multipart/alternative child container.
msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

# Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
# necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.
textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)

# Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
msg_body.attach(textpart)
msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

# Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
att = MIMEApplication(open(ATTACHMENT, 'rb').read())

# Add a header to tell the email client to treat this part as an attachment,
# and to give the attachment a name.
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=os.path.basename(ATTACHMENT))

# Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
# parent container.
msg.attach(msg_body)

# Add the attachment to the parent container.
msg.attach(att)
#print(msg)
try:
    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_raw_email(
        Source=SENDER,
        Destinations=[
            RECIPIENT
        ],
        RawMessage={
            'Data':msg.as_string(),
        },
        ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Answer (score 8):

To expand upon @adkl's answer, Amazon's own example is using older Python way of handling emails and attachments. Nothing wrong with that, just that current documentation on those modules is not comprehensive and might be confusing for new users like me.

Here's simple example on forming message with CSV attachment.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage


def create_email_message(sender: str, recipients: list, title: str, text: str,
                         attachment: BytesIO, file_name: str) -> EmailMessage:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = title
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    msg.set_content(text)
    data = attachment.read()
    msg.add_attachment(
        data,
        maintype="text",
        subtype="csv",
        filename=file_name
    )
    return msg

# Client init, attachment file creation here

message = create_email_message(...)
try:
    ses.send_raw_email(
        Source=sender,
        Destinations=recipients,
        RawMessage={'Data': message.as_string()}
    )
except ClientError as e:
    logger.exception(f"Cannot send email report to {recipients}: {e}")
else:
    logger.info("Sent report successfully")
```

In this example I use `BytesIO` object as a source for attachment, but you can use any file-like object that supports `read()` method.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to send an attachment:

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import boto.ses


AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'HEREYOURACCESSKEY'
AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'HEREYOURSECRETKEY'

class Email(object):

    def __init__(self, to, subject):
        self.to = to
        self.subject = subject
        self.text = None
        self.attachment = None


    def text(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def add_attachment(self, attachment):
        self.attachment = attachment

    def send(self, from_addr=None, file_name = None):

        connection = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
            'us-east-1',
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY
        )
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = self.subject
        msg['From'] = from_addr
        msg['To'] = self.to

        part = MIMEApplication(self.attachment)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
        part.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8')

        msg.attach(part)

        # the message body
        part = MIMEText(self.text)
        msg.attach(part)

        return connection.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),source=from_addr,destinations=self.to)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    email = Email(to='toMail@gmail.com', subject='Your subject!')
    email.text('This is a text body.')
    #you could use StringIO.StringIO() to get the file value
    email.add_attachment(yourFileValue)
    email.send(from_addr='from@mail.com',file_name="yourFile.txt")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Only attach code in reply is not a good answer. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline to refine your reply.

Comment: this seems to be boto for python 2.7, not boto3

Comment: As I struggled with this a bit, I created a working example for boto3 now [here](https://www.binspeak.de/ses-mail-mit-python-boto3-und-anhangen-versenden/). The explanation is German, but the code should speak for itself.

Comment: If you want to send a html email, set `part = MIMEText(self.text, 'html')`. The second parameter is the content subtype and defaults to 'plain'.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the class I ended up using. Drop into a Lambda file and use it.

Accepts a list of filenames for attachments. Sends `HTML` email. Changes `\n` for `<br />`

I saved the below class [1] as `emailer.py` and use as:

```py
from emailer import Emailer

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  # ...
  emailer = Emailer()
  emailer.send(
    to=email_recipients_list, 
    subject=subject_string, 
    fromx=from_address_string, 
    body=email_body_string, 
    attachments=attachments_list
  )
```

[1]

```py
import boto3
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


class Emailer(object):
    """ send email with attachments """
    
    def send(self, to, subject, fromx, body=None, content=None, attachments=None):
        """ sends email with attachments
        
        Parameters:
            * to (list or comma separated string of addresses): recipient(s) address
            * fromx (string): from address of email
            * body (string, optional): Body of email ('\n' are converted to '< br/>')
            * content (string, optional): Body of email specified as filename
            * attachments (list, optional): list of paths of files to attach
        """

        if attachments is None:
            attachments = []

        self.to = to
        self.subject = subject
        self.fromx = fromx
        self.attachment = None
        self.body = body
        self.content = content
        self.attachments = attachments
        
        if type(self.to) is list:
            self.to = ",".join(self.to)
        
        
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        
        message['Subject'] = self.subject
        message['From'] = self.fromx
        message['To'] = self.to
        if self.content and os.path.isfile(self.content):
            part = MIMEText(open(str(self.content)).read().replace("\n", "<br />"), "html")
            message.attach(part)
        elif self.body:
            part = MIMEText(self.body.replace("\\n", "<br />").replace("\n", "<br />"), "html")
            message.attach(part)
            
        
        for attachment in self.attachments:
            part = MIMEApplication(open(attachment, 'rb').read())
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment.split("/")[-1])
            message.attach(part)
            
        ses = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')
        
        response = ses.send_raw_email(
            Source=message['From'],
            Destinations=message['To'].split(","),
            RawMessage={
                'Data': message.as_string()
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be implemented using python version 2.7.x

Following is the working code for this--

[Note - The 'sender' and 'recipients' that you add must be verified in AWS SES. OR SES must be moved from 'sandbox' state to 'Production' state

```
import os
import boto3
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


def create_multipart_message(email_metadata):        
    sender = email_metadata['sender_']
    recipients = email_metadata['recipients_']
    title = email_metadata['title_']
    text = email_metadata['text_']
    html = email_metadata['body_']
    attachments = email_metadata['attachments_']

    multipart_content_subtype = 'alternative' if text and html else 'mixed'
    msg = MIMEMultipart(multipart_content_subtype)
    msg['Subject'] = title
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)

    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    if text:
        part = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        msg.attach(part)
    if html:
        part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
        msg.attach(part)

    # Add attachments
    for attachment in attachments or []:
        with open(attachment, 'rb') as f:
            part = MIMEApplication(f.read())
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(attachment))
            msg.attach(part)

    return msg


def send_mail(email_metadata):
        #sender: str, recipients: list, title: str, text: str=None, html: str=None, attachments: list=None) -> dict:
    """
    Send email to recipients. Sends one mail to all recipients.
    The sender needs to be a verified email in SES.
    """
    msg = create_multipart_message(email_metadata)
    ses_client = boto3.client('ses')  # Use your settings here
    return ses_client.send_raw_email(
        Source=email_metadata['sender_'],
        Destinations=email_metadata['recipients_'],
        RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()}
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    email_metadata = {
    "sender_" : "The Sender <the_sender@email.com>",
    "recipients_" : ['Recipient One <recipient_1@email.com>','Recipient two <recipient_2@email.com>'],
    "title_" : "Email title here",
    "text_" : "The text version\nwith multiple lines.",
    "body_" : "<html><head></head><body><h1>A header 1</h1><br>Some text.",
    "attachments_" : ['/path/to/file1/filename1.txt','/path/to/file2/filename2.txt']
    }

    response_ = send_mail(email_metadata)
    print(response_)
```

Comment: avoid python2 like the plague!

Comment: I've tried to run this code using python3 and it's working fine. Thanks for the answer @aayush-dalvi